# Why is "web/unsecure/base_url" missing in `core_config_data`?

Tags: database

I try to create a copy of my project.

First I duplicated the project and the database, then I tried to change `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` in `core_config_data` to the new url.

But I noticed that they are not appearing in the database? This is all:

[image]

I also changed `app/etc/local.xml` to point at my new database.

This is what I get in the frontend right now:

> There has been an error processing your request SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
>
> No such file or directory
>
> ...
>
> Error log record number: 372605216729

Comment: I noticed that my duplicated database is only 15 MB big, I think I have to import the data again. This time I packed the 1.5 GB SQL file as zip, now it is only 82 MB ! I will report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because Phpmyadmin failed to import the sql file completly. I had to import each table by hand to make it work.

Hint: Use MySQL console to create a dump of the database, then import the dump via MySQL. Turn off FK-Check.

Answer (score 1):

Try following query

For unsecure path

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%web/unsecure/base_url%'
```

For secure path

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%web/secure/base_url%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Phpmyadmin has some restrictions to import a SQL file if the file is too big.

So you can do the following:

```
mysql -u {username} -p {databasename} < /home/{cpanelpath}/pubic_html/yourfile.sql
```

Hit Enter and enter the password.

Comment: What exactly is your command doing?